# Prioritize virtual machine bandwidth

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, ping, bandwidth, games

I installed a Windows Server 2012 virtual machine (VM Ware Workstation) on my Debian server that I rented (to which I have SSH access only, and which is in another city with over 1 GB bandwidth) to host some Half-Life derivative game (L4D2).

While I'm in the game, I get some connection lags occasionally. It's like the connection is perfect and my ping/latency is 20 ms, but for a second or two, I get a major lag. I investigated the issue, trying to understand the cause of this, and I found that whenever my Linux server has an action related to internet, the lag happens. For example, if my mail server gets an e-mail, it gets the game to lag. It's like the virtual machine is given minimal priority.

**How can I let the virtual machine have higher priority for internet?** I've been reading a little, and I understand the traffic shaping works in a way that *limits* other programs bandwidth. But apparently I have to do the opposite now. I have to tell Linux: Please don't ignore the virtual machine and give it higher priority.

Can this be done?

If you require any additional information or tests, please ask.

PS: I haven't used a Linux half-life server because I have addons that have huge incompatibility issues. I spent a week recompiling Sourcemod addons and gave up. I don't want to spend 2 months just for a game server.

Comment: Is the underlying host a physical host, or is it virtualized itself?

Comment: Regarding *But apparently I have to do the opposite now.*: That's not how traffic shaping works. You cannot create resources out of nothing. You need to limit other VMs to indirectly prioritize this one.

Comment: @ManuelFaux Thanks for responding. It's a root server. I know that one creates limits, as you mentioned... that's why I'm asking the question... it's a problem!

Comment: So why not limiting all other VMs in their bandwidth?

Comment: @ManuelFaux It's the only VM on the server. The root server is a linux server, with many, many services (webserver, e-mail server, cloud, etc...), and one VM that contains this game server.

Comment: I'd recommend to use the server itself only as a pure hypervisor without any additional services and create at least one VM for the services the hypervisor provides right now. Then you have better control over your available resources. Also from a security perspective it's better if the hypervisor itself does not run any service (it's more likely that it gets compromised with any additional service, and if the hypervisor gets compromised, basically all your VMs might be comproised, too).